# Index.html without XAMPP

Tags: html, .htaccess, indexing, xampp

Is it possible to automatically load *index.html* on a system folder without using XAMPP, IIS or similar?

It is for a school project and I can't use them, so I have to open the file putting the path (`C:/...`) into the address bar.

I know I could use `.htaccess`, but I don't know what to write and if it gets read without any web server solutions!

Comment: You can try with this extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer for Visual Studio Code.

GIF: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/master/images/Screenshot/vscode-live-server-explorer-menu-demo-1.gif

Comment: @GeorgiGrigorov I can't install extensions... I have to open the file on my school computer, and I can just put a folder there and open it from the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can get a little tricky... but is possible without any "administrator" privileges, nor without installing anything.

1. Download [Python 3.8.2 - Windows x86-64 embeddable zip file](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.2/python-3.8.2-embed-amd64.zip)
2. Create a folder on "python" on the c:\
3. Extract the "Zip" file into this folder
4. Change the folder name from "python-3.8.2-embed-amd64" to "python_src"
5. Create a folder named "python_html"
6. The folder structure should look like:

   ```
   c:\python\
   c:\python\python_src\
   c:\python\python_html\
   ```
7. Create a file named "webserver.py" in the "c:\python\python_html" folder
8. Place the following code into that file:

   ```
   #webserver.py

   import http.server
   import socketserver

   PORT = 80
   Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

   with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
       print("serving at port", PORT)
       httpd.serve_forever()
   ```
9. Save and close the file
10. Create index.html file in the "python_html" folder and place the following code in that file:

    ```
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Web Title</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Python Web Server File</h1>
            <p>Congratulations! The HTTP Server is working!</p>
        </body>
    </html>
    ```
11. Open the "Command Prompt" and type the following commands

    ```
    cd\
    cd python\python_html\
    c:\python\python_src\python ./webserver.py
    ```
12. Open a web browser and navigate to "http://localhost/"

Once you have confirmed this works, you can build an entire website within that "python_html" folder. As long as you don't close the command prompt it will continue acting as a "Web Server".

Comment: Yup, I also have to do this occasionally ;)

Answer (score 0):

> I know I could use *.htaccess*

`.htaccess` is an Apache (Web Server) config file, so unless you have Apache installed (ie. the "A" in XAMPP) then you can't use that. (If `.htaccess` was available then `index.html` would likely load automatically anyway.)

On Apache, being able to load `index.html` by default when requesting a directory requires mod_dir (an Apache module). In this case, mod_dir issues an internal subrequest for the DirectoryIndex - this all requires additional processes.

> I can't install extensions... I have to open the file on my school computer

If you can't install *anything* then you can't do this I'm afraid. You appear to be limited to direct file requests.

When using a webserver (such as Apache or IIS) then you have a differentiation between a URL and a filesystem path. The webserver maps the URL to a filesystem path. Without a webserver you don't have that abstraction.

There are lighter webservers, other than Apache and IIS, but you need to install *something* extra.

---

Just give your file(s) meaningful names (ie. not `index.html`) and use those instead? eg. `fox-project.html`

Comment: I was going to suggest, if you have Python installed then you can use Python's built-in webserver with `py -m http.server <port>`  - although I see @LarryAtherton has provided a very detailed answer in that regard!